# Combing a categorical variable to create a new categorical variable in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

**UPDATE**

I want to create a new categorical variable based on an existing categorical variable within my dataframe. The way I want to do this, is by combining the values of some levels and create a different level

Here is a working

```
fac1 <- c("A","B", "C", "E", "F", "10", "11", "12", "19")
x1       <- c(NA,2,NA,3,4,5,6,7,NA)
data1    <- data.frame(fac1,x1)  

    fac1 x1
1    A NA
2    B  2
3    C NA
4    E  3
5    F  4
6   10  5
7   11  6
8   12  7
9   19 NA
```

Considering that `data1` is the working dataframe, `fact1` is a categorical variable. Based on its levels seen above, and their values shown in `x1`, I want to create a new categorical variable that combines the levels in `fac1` to create new levels and takes the **average** of the values in their respective values shown in `x`.

**Expected result:**

```
     fac1  fac2 x1
1    A     A NA
2    B     B  2
3    C   C-E  3
4    E   C-E  3
5    F     F  4
6   10 10-12  6
7   11 10-12  6
8   12 10-12  6
9   19    19 NA
```

**UPDATE 2**

Most of the answers work, per for some reason the values in ``x1" are filled with the means -- I have accounted per different categories but same problem. I cannot understand the source of the problem in my database, and I suspect this is related to the `mean` function.

here what I get from in the original database of mine, where `x1` is the variable that replaces the old values as per this example.

```
 ind   year  HH_index cou   ind_2 ind2     x1
   <fct> <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <chr> <fct> <dbl>
 1 A     1995        NA AT    A     A     0.188
 2 B     1995        NA AT    B     B     0.188
 3 10-12 1995        NA AT    10-12 10-12 0.188
 4 10    1995        NA AT    10-12 10-12 0.188
 5 11    1995        NA AT    10-12 10-12 0.188
 6 12    1995        NA AT    10-12 10-12 0.188
 7 13    1995        NA AT    13-15 13    0.188
 8 14    1995        NA AT    13-15 14    0.188
 9 D     1995        NA AT    D-E   D-E   0.188
10 15    1995        NA AT    13-15 15    0.188
```

Comment: Concerning update 2. Always make sure that your example is representative of what you're trying to do. I can see a `year` column that you didn't mention in your example. Do you group by year as well?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want would look something like this, assuming you only want to combine the C and E lines:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)
data1[fac1 %in% c("C", "E"), c("fac2", "x1") := .("C-E", mean(x1))]
data1[is.na(fac2), fac2 := fac1]
```

Although, in your case, the mean of `x1` for `fac1 %in% c("C", "E")` is not `3`, it is `NA`. If you want to remove the `NA`, just add `na.rm = TRUE` to the mean.

Comment: If I want to group more than C-E, and do the same same calculations per other categorical variables per year --- to apply the same rule for each possible year.

Comment: So you want every possible combination of fac1?

Comment: No, say there are other levels -- say F and G, so I want to create C-D plus F-G, but A and B leave them as they are.

Comment: You could, in that case, simply repeat line 3 in my answer for the other categorical fac1 values you want to group. As in: `data1[fac1 %in% c("C", "D"), c("fac2", "x1") := .("C-D", mean(x1))]` ... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The key in your process is to find a way to specify your grouping philosophy in a way that the process can understand. The easiest way to do this, given that you want to group different values together, is to create a look up table of your grouping, which will be used by the process.

See an example below:

```
# example data
fac1 <- c("A","B", "C", "E", "F", "10", "11", "12", "19")
x1       <- c(NA,2,NA,3,4,5,6,7,NA)
data1    <- data.frame(fac1,x1, stringsAsFactors = F) 

library(dplyr)

# specify values to group together as a look up table
# (this is what you should create to specify your grouping philosophy)
look_up = data.frame(fac1 = c("C","E","10","12"),
                     group = c(1,1,2,2), stringsAsFactors = F)

look_up

#   fac1 group
# 1    C     1
# 2    E     1
# 3   10     2
# 4   12     2


# update look up table
# (you can create a look up table like this straight away if you prefer)
look_up = look_up %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(fac2 = paste0(fac1, collapse = "-")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

look_up

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   fac1  fac2 
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 C     C-E  
# 2 E     C-E  
# 3 10    10-12
# 4 12    10-12


data1 %>%
  left_join(look_up, by="fac1") %>%
  group_by(fac2 = ifelse(is.na(fac2), fac1, fac2)) %>%
  mutate(x1 = mean(x1, na.rm = T)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   fac1     x1 fac2 
#   <chr> <dbl> <chr>
# 1 A       NaN A    
# 2 B         2 B    
# 3 C         3 C-E  
# 4 E         3 C-E  
# 5 F         4 F    
# 6 10        6 10-12
# 7 11        6 11   
# 8 12        6 10-12
# 9 19      NaN 19
```

Comment: what if I want to group more than two values ? say combine `C` and `E` to create the `C-E`, but also want many more groups, say have `F` and `H` that needs to be combined to get `F-H` as well.

Comment: In principle it works, but there is a problem in my dataframe that cannot figure out. Can you please check my update?

Comment: Looks like the mean value is the same for all rows. Maybe that's the mean of all values, which suggests that you don't use your grouping correctly when you calculate the means.

Comment: yes, I do per year. I did not mention this because I assumed was redundant with any number of groups byond two. But, tried also without year. Still I get the outcome in update2 and cannot undrerstand the problem. I applied both your suggested answer and the one by @Jimbou, same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `plyr`'s `mapvalues` function to rename the factor labels together with `tidyverse`. Where `from` is a vector of the items to replace and `to` is a vector of same length of replacement values. Then group and calculate the new `x1` value.

```
library(tidyverse)
data1 %>% 
  mutate(fac2=plyr::mapvalues(fac1, from = c("C", "E", 10:12), 
                                    to = rep(c("C-E", "10-12"),c(2,3)))) %>% 
  group_by(fac2) %>% 
  mutate(x1=mean(x1, na.rm = T))
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   fac2 [6]
  fac1     x1 fac2 
  <fct> <dbl> <fct>
1 A       NaN A    
2 B         2 B    
3 C         3 C-E  
4 E         3 C-E  
5 F         4 F    
6 10        6 10-12
7 11        6 10-12
8 12        6 10-12
9 19      NaN 19
```

Comment: In principle it works, but there is a problem in my dataframe that cannot figure out. Can you please check my update?

Comment: The grouping is going wrong I guess. Perhaps due to  a second `ind2` column?